# Envio de correos periodicamente

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Llevo  dias investigando cual es la mejor manera de enviar correos "recordatorios de pago" a los clientes de mi sistema periodicamente.

He encontrado diferentes gemas que deberian funcionar pero la documentacion no es suficiente, haciendo que me quede estancado en el proceso.

Necesito que el usuario administrador del sistema tenga la opcion de elegir con que periodiciedas se enviaran estos correos electronicos. cual gema me  recomiendan

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo la gema [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever),la cual te permite programar tareas que se ejecuten periódicamente, incluyendo envío de correos.

Para que el administrador pueda decidir la periodicidad, puedes generar una tabla en la bd (i.e. un modelo) con un campo para que ahí puedas guardar la periodicidad con la que quieras que se envíen los correos. De esa forma el administrador podría cambiar cada vez que se requiera.

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes hacer es iniciar con la configuración, aunque la documentación esté incompleta, siempre puedes regresara SO para buscar ayuda en los puntos donde se presenten dudas o problemas.